# Javascript string replace weirdness -- $$$$ gets collapsed to $$ -- what's the reason behind this result?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

At work, I was encountering a problem where users of our application were receiving messages featuring an invalid unicode character (0xffff), which according to the standard, should never be mapped to a symbol.

As a quick work aound I did the following:

```
badStr.replace(/\uffff/g, " ");
```

Which works as expected, and lets the user continue using the application until we find a better solution.

However, while I was playing around with this, I randomly tried a string replacement of "$$$$" which somehow got collapsed "$$".

You can see for yourself. Try pasting the following lines in your browser url bar:

```
javascript: alert(String.fromCharCode(0xffff).replace(/\uffff/g, "@@@@"));
```

results in @@@@

but

```
javascript: alert(String.fromCharCode(0xffff).replace(/\uffff/g, "$$$$"));
```

results in $$

This actually seems to be a problem with any string replacement, with $$$$ as the string replacement.

Both:

```
javascript: alert(String.fromCharCode(0x1234).replace(/\u1234/g, "$$$$"));
javascript: alert("hella".replace("h", "$$$$"));
```

result in the $$ collapse.

Any ideas as to why the string replacement behaves this way?

Comment: I do not know an answer to your question, but where does this character come from in the first place? How does it make it into your messaging system?

Comment: Executive emails. I'm guessing they're cutting and pasting things, with multiple utf encodings, and somehow they're ending up with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because `$` in the replace string has special meaning (group expansion). Have a look at this example:

```
alert("foo".replace(/(.*)/, "a$1b"));
```

That's why `$$` is interpreted as `$`, for the case where you would need to actually replace something by `$1` (literally, without group expansion):

```
alert("foo".replace(/(.*)/, "a$$1b"));
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter.

Comment: See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Thanks, added the documentation link.

Comment: Crazy wild. I never knew about this!

Answer (score 2):

The `$` sign is a special character in the replacement argument to denote sub-matches from parentheses in the regex pattern (`$1`, `$2`, etc.). So to get a `$` you have to "escape" it by typing `$$`. Which is what you did twice.

Answer (score 1):

The $ in a replace string is used to signal the use of the match groups $1, $2 etc, si to put a $ into the replace string you need to use two of them.